# Stretch Layer when overflow

Tags: html, css, layer

I have a div-Element with some content in it. The content has some Java-Dropdown-Links in it and so the length of the content varies very much (vertical).

When I use "overflow-y: scroll" the content is still in the Layer and a scrollbar appears (it works perfectly).

But I want the layer to stretch vertical so I can use the "Main-Scrollbar" from the browser window instead of having a scrollbar in the container/layer.

```
<div id="Layer1"
style="position:absolute;left:13%;top:160px;width:75%;height:150%;z-index:2;
opacity=0.50;overflow-y: scroll"><?php include($mitte);?></div>
```

What CSS attributes do I have to add to make this works? The height of the Layer should just stretch (vertical) in the moment when the content of the php-File becomes bigger.

Thank you!

Comment: Change the height of the div to auto `height: auto;` this will cause the DIV to resize along with the content

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Nice i'll change to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of the DIV to auto `height: auto;` this will cause the DIV to resize along with the content